# Rails display notice in non-english language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notice

I have this code:

```
  if @art.save
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully saved!"
  end
```

But I need something like this (in russian):

```
  if @art.save
    flash[:notice] = "Успешно сохранено в бд!"
  end
```

Sure it's giving me errors, but are there any ways to use non-english notices in RoR? Or must I use locales? Then how do I translate only that notice? (in html is in .n1 class)

Comment: What errors does it give you? It should work fine.

Comment: Is your file using UTF8 encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing a magic encoding comment. Add this to the top of the file

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

Also, a **much** better way is to use a built-in [internationalization api](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html). With it, your code will look like this:

```
flash[:notice] = I18n.t(:successful_save)
```

And all your russian strings will be contained within `config/locales/ru.yml` and won't cause any troubles in the source code.